# Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::loadAllAttributes()

Tags: magento-1.9, category, api

I have trouble with some API calls, which results in this error in the log.
Call to undefined method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat::loadAllAttributes()`

As far as I can see the mentioned `loadAllAttributes()`-method is supposed to exist in the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php` file. However, this is not the case. I have also tried checking a completely clean install of Magento, but can't find the mentioned method in the clean version of `Category.php` either.

Does anyone have a clue to what causes this error and how to fix it?

Comment: This is because you're using flat tables for your products, what are you trying to achieve with this development? You'll need to use the full collection to call that function.

Comment: I am simply trying to get a bought extension to work. The mentioned error is the result from the log, when using the extension.

I have asked the developer whether it's caused by using flat tables, but he's responding that he has tested the extension with flat tables and gotten it to work..

Any other ideas?

Comment: I might trying to disable flat tables just to see if it works. Can I do that on a live site without risking any damage?

Comment: I changed the table setting and everything seems to work now. Thank you for your help :-)